# VSCode - import errors and interpreter errors

Tags: python, debugging, visual-studio-code, import

I have several imports in my current code:

```py
from flask import Flask
import datetime as dt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
```

When I run this in VSCODE I am getting this error:
[image: this error]

However, running this in jupyter notebook has no problems. When I looked online it said to use python interpreter but when I go to do that I get this error:
[image: 2]

And another error:

Anaconda prompt says modules/packages are installed but when I run pip install in default windows terminal it says pip has no module:
[image: has no module]

Comment: You seem to have installed different versions of Python. Install the libraries in the correct interpreter.

Answer (score 0):

Delete and reinstall Python extensions according to the same [problem](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/14959) on github.

The second problem is related to the location of your Python interpreter. You need to choose the correct interpreter. I still recommend using one Python version in one environment. You can use other Python versions in virtual environment, so it won't lead to confusion.